# Maximise cell value using less than/ greater than in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I am trying to maximise a cell value by applying several less than conditions. I want to adjust the values of the four less than conditions to maximise the cell value. The values can be negative as well as positive

I had looked at using solver for this but as I couldn't find information related to less than/greater than filters assumed this was inappropriate. Below is my formula

```
=SUMIFS('2016-19'!$BG$2:$BG$33583, '2016-19'!$BC$2:$BC$33583, "<" & $B$84, '2016-19'!$BE$2:$BE$33583, "<" & $B$87, '2016-19'!$AU$2:$AU$33583, "<" & $B$86, '2016-19'!$BB$2:'2016-19'!$BB$33583,"<" & $B$85)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: To be clear I need to adjust the values of B84:B87 such that this maximises the cell with this formula in (L67). By maximises I mean calculates the optimum filters such that L67 is as high as it can be. I have looked at Goal Seek and Solver to do this but can't get Solver output to work which I assume is because of the formula and goal seek as I understand requires a specific target and I can only use one cell to vary when I need to vary all 4

Comment: What do you mean by "maximise"?

Comment: the cell value represents profit. I want to identify the values of the filters that maximise the profit (cell value) that this formula is written in

Comment: The question is not fully clear to me. If you focus on the maximum value you can usually use `=MAX()`. I however assume that this is not what you are looking for as a response?

Comment: If I follow what you ask, then perhaps you should be looking at Goalseek or using the Solver.

Comment: @M. S. yes that's not what I'm asking. I want to adjust the values of B84:B87 such that it maximises the cell with this formula. I want to work out what the optimum values are for B84:B87. As I understand MAX() it will just tell me what the largest value is. .

Comment: @SolarMike. yes I have looked at both. I didn't think I could use goal seek as I need to set the target value to a specific value and I tried solver but the GRG one ran and didn't return a result. The 2nd method did not run and the 3rd evolutionary ran but this resulted in a #DIV0 error

Comment: That sounds like your model needs attention perhaps it is unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

This could solve your problem:

If you have only one input variable you want to optimise for a maximum output, select `Data` -> `What-if-analysis` -> `Goal Seek`. Within Goal Seek, you select the input variable (e.g. `B84`), the maximum value you want to achieve and the output variable for which this maximum value should apply.

If you have more than one variable, you can add the Excel Data Analysis Add-in in the Excel settings to perform multiple regression analyses for multiple input variables. Hope that helps.